# Why does d3 date axis fail in Firefox for some particular date domains?

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js

I'm using Windows 10, Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit), Firefox 49.0.1, and d3 v. 4.2.6. The code below works fine in Chrome:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dates = ["2015-10-11","2015-10-14","2015-10-15","2015-10-16","2015-10-19"];
var w = 600;
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
dates.forEach(function(d,i) {dates[i]=parseDate(d)});
console.log(dates);
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width", w);
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, 500]).domain(d3.extent(dates, function(d) { return d; }));
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50,50)").call(xAxis);
</script>        
</body>
</html>
```

But it fails in Firefox leaving this message in the console:

> Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
>   newInterval/interval.range@d3.v4.js:5094:8
>   calendar/scale.ticks@d3.v4.js:7018:13
>   axis@d3.v4.js:8888:54
>   selection_call@d3.v4.js:7615:3
>   @file:///C:/test/test.html:18:1

Also if I change the first date to "2015-10-12" then it will work in both browsers.
I looked up for some answer in those lines in d3.v4.js but it was fruitless. I'm no black belt in javascript so I might have missed something.
I also have searched the Internet but found no explanation for this odd behavior.
Does anyone have any clue?

Edit: Tested in a virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04 and obtained exactly the same result. Worked ok in Chrome and had a script terminated by timeout error in Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical 1.0.

Comment: It works for me in Firefox 49, except i have Windows 7 enterprise rather than 10

Comment: It works for me: Firefox 45, Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mike Bostock from d3 and his suggestion to use d3.utcParse and d3.scaleUtc now Firefox is working as expected!